# getting video file from input and displaying it in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using this code to get my hands on an image that was just "uploaded" into browser using `<input type="file">` and sending data to some component that uses it.

```
 fileReady(e) {
    let file: File = e[0];
    let image = new Image();
    let src: string;

    image.onload = function () {
      src = image.src;
      //do something with image

    }.bind(this);
    src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    image.src = src;
  }
```

This work well for images. Next goal, is to make it work with videos too. There is unfortunately no `Video()` constructor and `HTMLVideoElement` also doesn't do the trick. How should  I rewrite this code so that it can handle videos?

Comment: you can use `Blob` type

Comment: Could you share an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
fileReady(e) {
      const file: File = e[0];
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onloadend = (event: any) => {
        const arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
        const fileType = "video/mpeg";
        const blob = new Blob(arrayBuffer , {type: fileType });
        const src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        video.src = src;
      };
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I am getting an error on the line: e.target.result, saying that result does not exist on type EventTarget

Comment: @sanjihan i fixed

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing a typecast: const beforeResult = <FileReader>e.target; . And for future readers... Blob takes an array of blob parts, as in  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer] , {type: fileType });

Comment: Hello @ЮраПанарин can you take a look at my question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978624/get-an-image-from-a-video-file

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a latest update in the answer,

```
const blob = new Blob(arrayBuffer , {type: fileType });
```

will give error that the Blob needs an iterable.
So the fix is :

`const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: fileType });`